# jquery function summary metadata respected in visual studio

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio

I'm having trouble finding any helpful information related to my question, and possibly due to the fact that I have the terminology wrong in my search.

In Visual Studio when writing C#, to add summary metadata the shortcut is to use the `///` syntax. This tags your class or function with descriptive data about what it does. What I'm trying to achieve is that same type of functionality but with my .js files.

here is my object>function and it's meta data.

```
_Search = {
    /// <summary>
    /// Does ajax post to conroller action to get partial view
    /// <param name="params">parameter object</param>
    /// <param name="mrn">url to controller action method</param>
    /// <param name="name">the result element that will be overwritten with the returned parital view markup</param>
    doSearch: function (params, url, $results) {
        $results.block({
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>'
        });

        $.post(url, params, function (data) {
            $results.html(data);
            $results.unblock();
        });
    }
}
```

and what i was hoping to acheive would be the description of each parameter, but as you can see that's not the case. 
[image]

Is there a way I can acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you must add the /// stuff inside your function.

```
function doStuff() {
    /// <summary>
    /// Does stuff
    /// </summary>

    // TODO: Do stuff
}
```